# How long is a long tap?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

As I understand it, there is no "long tap" event in JavaScript - this isn't a huge problem because I can start a timer on "touchstart" and check to see if the user it still interacting with the same element after X seconds. My question is: **how long is X seconds?**

The reason I ask this is that [it seems to be possible to adjust the duration on an Android device](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006989?hl=en-GB) but is there a list of times for the various options? Ideally, is there a JavaScript request of some kind that I can make to find out how long that duration is (or, at least, which option the user has chosen)? I'd like the duration of my timer to match the user's device for the sake of consistency, but I'd also like to honour any user preference for a shorter or longer duration, if possible.

A follow-up question (which might be a little out-of-scope and better asked in another part of the Stack Exchange, to be fair) is: is the idea of a "long tap" understood by all touch-enabled device users, such as those that use iPhones and iPads? (I'm an Android man and it's second nature to me, but I don't know how how unique I am.)

Comment: An extra thing to be wary of is that "long tap" generally performs a function in the browser, equivalent to right-click on desktop. I'm not sure if you'll be able to prevent that if there's no specific event to "prevent default" on.

Comment: @IMSoP usually that's covered by the [contextmenu event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event)

Comment: @IMSoP I should probably add that the `contextmenu` event fires after releasing the tap: `touchstart` -> hold -> `touchend` -> `contextmenu` - what I'm hoping to do is `touchstart` -> hold -> (custom "long tap" event)